# Nested Ajax request, good or bad practice?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have to make a sequence of Ajax post requests to server using jQuery, and each request is depends on the result of previous response, for example

```
preprocessing-data-Ajax(returns jobs_array){
    register-job-Ajax(returns job_id){
       for each prepared data index i{
           submit_job_Ajax(job_id, jobs_array[i]){
               if(last_returned_job){
                   unregister_job-Ajax(jon_id){
                       postprocessing-data-Ajax;
                   }                   
               }
           }
       } 
    }

}
```

This creates a huge chunk of unreadable code and very hard to debug. Just wondering if anyone knows how to avoid nested Ajax requests, or points me to an alternative solution.

Thanks!

Comment: If unreadability of code is the problem, use callback functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use success callbacks

```
$.ajax({
  url: "URL",
  data: "DATA",
  success: function(data) {

    //data contains the returned data
    //Next ajax here

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I am using callback functions, but I still do not like the code as It is less structured, maybe there is a design problem at the begining.